# std::set::find exception guarantees

Tags: c++, exception, stl, set

I'm currently writing exception-safe code and my design requires no throw guarantee for
set::find method.
I assume the comparator object always succeeds.
Does it imply set::find method will always succeed?

I thought about such a possibility after I have seen that according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase, set::erase method, with the same assumption, should always succeed and maybe there's a find in it (then it would be definetely worth a comment in documentation!)

The direct source for the problem is that I need to check whether an element is in a set and remove it from the set -- all that having no throw guarantee (it's in a catch block).

Comment: I'm not sure about the standard or any guarantees for set or any stl containers but I will say this.. One time I call vector::erase(v.end()).. It threw an exception.. I spent hours trying to find out why. Turns out my vector was empty. Not sure if this still happens or if std::set has this problem but it happened to me in gcc 4.8.1 for windows.. I ended up having to do an if statement checking if `vector::find != v.end()`. I think you might have to do that. That may be the only time you don't get an exception for sure?

Comment: @CantChoose This is undefined behavior, for an empty vector as much as for a non-empty vector. You cannot erase the first element past-the-end...

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames You should be glad it threw an exception. It's Undefined Behaviour AFAIK and could have erased your hard drive ;)

Answer (score 1):

[`std::set::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find):

> Return value
>
> Iterator to an element with key `key`. If no such element is found, past-the-end (see [end()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/end)) iterator is returned.

Neither the documentation nor the C++ Standard explicitly list any exception safety guarantees. However, the same rules spelled out for [`std::set::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase) apply here (§23.2.4.1 Exception safety guarantees [associative.reqmts.except]):

> `erase(k)` does not throw an exception unless that exception is thrown by the container’s `Compare` object (if any).

In essence, unless the `Compare` object throws an exception, `std::set::find` does not throw. Bjarne Stroustrup has the following to say in [The C++ Programming Language, Special Edition - Appendix E](http://www.stroustrup.com/3rd_safe.pdf):

> Fortunately, predicates rarely do anything that might throw an exception. However, user-defined `<`, `==`, and `!=` predicates must be taken into account when considering exception safety.

If you aren't providing any user-defined predicates you can assume `std::set::find` does not throw an exception. If you are, you should mark them as [`noexcept`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) to work safely in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 **§23.2.4.1 Exception safety guarantees [associative.reqmts.except]** lists all the exception safety requirements for associative containers (including `set`) and there is no mention made of `find`. So no, the standard does not guarantee that `find` never throws.

In the absence of undefined behavior and assuming a non-throwing comparator, I find it extremely unlikely that an implementation of the C++ standard library exists which will throw an exception from `set::find`. I would personally be comfortable with (a) wrapping `set::find` in a `noexcept` forwarding function so that the program will crash if such an "impossible" thing ever occurs, or (b) wrapping a particular `set::find` call in

```
auto it = foo.end();
try {
  it = foo.find(bar);
} catch(...) {}
```

and simply treating an exception as "not found."

Note that the ordering relation of associative containers is an easily-overlooked source of undefined behavior: § 23.2.4/2 requires the ordering relation to induce a strict weak ordering (as described in §25.4) on the key elements. An associative container instantiated with an ordering relation that is **not** a strict weak ordering does not have defined behavior, one possible outcome of which is throwing an exception from `find`.

Comment: I could easily imagine an exception being thrown if the comparator is not properly returning a strict weak ordering of the objects. I bet Dev Studio might.

Comment: @StilesCrisis Yes, throwing an exception is a possible outcome of undefined behavior in the program, as is any other imaginable result.

Comment: Writing my operator< to always return false is illogical, but on its face it's not going to throw. Standing alone, it's not undefined behavior--it's just incorrect results.

Comment: @StilesCrisis Standing alone it's not undefined behavior. If you use that `operator<` as the ordering relation of a standard library associative container then your program does not have defined behavior since § 23.2.4/2 requires such an ordering relation to induce a strict weak ordering on the elements of the key type.

Comment: Everything you're saying is true from a technical perspective, but it's not a helpful answer to OP's question. If you want to discuss cases where `find` might throw instead of succeeding, this is absolutely such a case, and it is a common mistake to make. If you want to avoid throwing in `find`, you need to be 100% sure your comparator always returns a strict weak ordering.